# Why does my dash only function properly if you aren't moving?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is the complete player controller file.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCont : MonoBehaviour
{
[Header("Movement Variables")]
public float moveSpeed;
private float speed;
public float maxSpeed;
public float acceleration;
public float dropSpeed;
public float slideSpeed;
public int direction = 1;

[Header("Jump Variables")]
public float jumpForce;
public int extraJumps;
private float jumpTimeCounter;
public float jumpTime;
private bool isJumping;
private int jumpNum;

[Header("Dash Variables")]
public float dashSpeed;
public float dashLength = .5f;
public float dashCooldown = 1f;
private float dashCounter;
public float dashCoolCounter;
private KeyCode _lastKeyCode;
private float doubleTapTime = 0.05f;
private bool doubleTap;
public bool isDashing;
public float dashTime;
public float maxDashTime;

[Header("GroundCheck Variables")]
public Transform groundCheck;
public float checkRadius;
public LayerMask whatIsGround;

[Header("Debug Variables")]
public Rigidbody2D rb;
public float moveInputX;
public float moveInputY;
public bool facingRight = true;
public bool isGrounded;
public bool downKey;
public float rbxVel;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    speed = moveSpeed;
    jumpNum = extraJumps;
}
void FixedUpdate()
{
    
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    moveInputX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    moveInputY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround);
    KeyChecks();
    Jump();
    GroundPound();
    Move();
    Dash();
}

void KeyChecks()
{
    //restricts movement in Y to only be downward
    if (moveInputY > 0)
    {
        moveInputY = 0;
    }
    //checks for player drop
    if (!isGrounded && moveInputY < 0)
    {
        downKey = true;
    }
    else
    {
        downKey = false;
    }
    //changes direction relative to keypress
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        direction = -1;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
    {
        direction = 1;
    }
}
void Jump()
{
    //sets jump number to user specified amount after touching ground
    if (isGrounded)
    {
        extraJumps = jumpNum;
    }

    //jumps and decrements extrajumps by 1
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && !downKey && extraJumps > 0)
    {
        isJumping = true;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
        extraJumps--;
    }

    //basic jump off of ground
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && extraJumps == 0 && isGrounded && !downKey)
    {
        isJumping = true;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
    }

    //checks for longkeypress of spacebar and increases length of jump
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && extraJumps > 1 && isJumping) // allows a hold down increase to jump while grounded
    {
        if (jumpTimeCounter > 0)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
            jumpTimeCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            jumpTimeCounter = jumpTime;
            isJumping = false;
        }
    }
}

void GroundPound()
{
    //ground pound keypress check
    if (!isGrounded && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
        if (!doubleTap && doubleTapTime > Time.time && _lastKeyCode == KeyCode.S)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, -1 * dropSpeed);
            Debug.Log("dashing right");
        }
        else
        {
            doubleTapTime = Time.time + 0.5f;
        }

        _lastKeyCode = KeyCode.S;
    }
}
void Move()
{
    //changes movement relative to input
    if (!isDashing)
    {
        if (isGrounded && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x * .999f, rb.velocity.y);
        }
        else if (moveInputX == 0 && isGrounded)
        {
            speed = moveSpeed;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x * .99f, rb.velocity.y);
        }
        else if (moveInputX == 0 && !isGrounded)
        {
            
            speed = moveSpeed;
            
        }
        else
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInputX * speed, moveInputY / 10 + rb.velocity.y);
        }
    }
    //checks player velocity
    rbxVel = rb.velocity.x;
    //increases speed relative to input direction
    if (moveInputX > 0 || moveInputX < 0)
    {
        speed += acceleration;
    }
    //caps speed
    if (speed > maxSpeed)
    {
        speed = maxSpeed;
    }
    //caps min speed
    if (speed < moveSpeed)
    {
        speed = moveSpeed;
    }
}

void Dash()
{

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        isDashing = true;
        if (isDashing && dashCoolCounter <= 0)
        {
            dashTime -= Time.deltaTime;
            dashCoolCounter = dashCooldown;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(dashSpeed * direction, rb.velocity.y);
            Debug.Log("Dash Started");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dashTime = maxDashTime;
        isDashing = false;
        Debug.Log("No Dash");
    }
    //resets dash cooldown
    if (dashCoolCounter > 0)
    {
        dashCoolCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
}

void Flip()
{
    facingRight = !facingRight;
    Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
    Scaler.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = Scaler;
}
}
```

When using the keys for movement (A, S) the dash doesn't function. Oddly enough the code is executing (I see my debug statement in console) but nothing physically changes.

When rewriting the code for the dash from: **rb.velocity = new Vector2(dashSpeed * direction, rb.velocity.y)** to:  *rb.velocity *= dashspeed** the dash will work without issue. The only downside to that is that the Y component of the RigidBody is being manipulated as well.

This has been an issue for days now, and I am just rewriting the post.

Any and all help is welcomed.

Comment: `and I am just rewriting the post.` .. I have seen it and that's the reason for my downvote. Stop deleting and reposting the same question! Rather work on its content quality. You give is a huge code and tell us there is a problem with it .. could you reduce it to the minimum required code to reproduce the issue? I doubt e.g. that `Flip`, `Jump`, `GroundPound` are all related to your issue ...

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting isDashing = false too soon. It gets set to false as soon as you let go of Shift which allows Move to execute its code and change your rigidbody's velocity back to normal move.

Didn't test this, but give it a shot and see if it works the way you want it to.

```
void Dash()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {     
        if (!isDashing && dashCoolCounter <= 0)
        {
            isDashing = true;
            dashTime = 0;
            dashCoolCounter = dashCooldown;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(dashSpeed * direction, rb.velocity.y);
            Debug.Log("Dash Started");
        }
        else if(isDashing)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(dashSpeed * direction, rb.velocity.y);
            dashTime += Time.deltaTime;
            if(dashTime >= maxDashTime)
            {
                isDashing = false;
                Debug.Log("No Dash");
            }     
        }
    }

    // resets dash cooldown
    if (dashCoolCounter > 0)
    {
        dashCoolCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```